# Can i show a pop up for the user to perform an action in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium. Basically i want to go to the database and change the date and then restart a service to simulate the emails in my web application. Is there any way i can do this through selenium using Java like show a pop up to the user to perform the said action and then click OK on the pop up to continue the execution?

TIA

Comment: This kinda defeats the purpose of automation... waiting on a user prompt. Either create a config file where you change settings or better yet, just write Java code to execute your db query from your script at the right time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. When an alert apears, selenium is not performing anything until alert is confirmed or closed (manualy or by code execution). There are few examples I'm using:

```
public void msg(String string_msg, String string_tit) {
    JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
    dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);  
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(dialog, string_msg, string_tit, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
public void msg_opt(String string_msg, String string_tit) {
    Object[] btn_text = {"Continue"};       
    JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
    dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);  
    JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(dialog, string_msg, string_tit, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, null, btn_text, null);
}
public void msg_results(String string, String[] strings) {
    JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
    dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    dialog.setLocation(700, 800);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(dialog, strings, get_results_title(), JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
public void msg_sms_results(String string, String[] strings) {
    JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
    dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    dialog.setLocation(1100, 880);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(dialog, strings, string, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
public void msg_err(String string_msg, String string_tit) {
    final JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
    dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(dialog, string_tit, string_msg, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, null);
}
```

Even some UI elements can be used. Another example:

```
public void uvodni_nastaveni() {        
    JCheckBox b1 = new JCheckBox("Zobrazovat dialogy s výsledky", false);
    JCheckBox b2 = new JCheckBox("Archivovat soubor s výsledky", true);
    JCheckBox b3 = new JCheckBox("Po dokončení smazat exportní soubory", true);     
    JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
    Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
    box.add(b1);box.add(b2);
    if (today_weekday_str() == "MONDAY") {box.add(b3);} 
    dialog.add(box);
    dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    Object[] btn_text = {"Continue"};       
    int result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(dialog, box, "Nastavení testu", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, btn_text, null);
    if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
        if (b1.isSelected() == true) {zobrazovat_vysledky = true;}
        else {zobrazovat_vysledky = false;}             
        if (b2.isSelected() == true) {archivovat_soubor_s_vysledky = true;}
        else {archivovat_soubor_s_vysledky = false;}        
        if (b3.isSelected() == true) {smazat_exporty = true;}
        else {smazat_exporty = false;}
    }
    else {}
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try implementing this